# Google Documents List API deprecated: how can one manipulate spreadsheets in Python now?

Tags: python, excel, google-apps-script, google-api, google-api-python-client

Like many others, I have an application that relies on [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) to  manipulate Google Spreadsheets with Python.

Unfortunately, gspread relies on the Documents List API, which is [being](https://assembly.com/gridspree/bounties/5) [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/). Without much in the way of good spreadsheet libraries out there -- and given the pitiful documentation of the Drive API -- what's next?

Can anyone point me to new methodology to manipulate spreadsheets (e.g., opening worksheets, writing values to specific cells, etc.) via the Drive API and/or other libraries?

What tools (or combinations of them) can we use now?

Comment: Spreadsheets api is not deprecated. Only docsList. Not sure why that library uses docList, probably to create new files. The official spreadsheets api docs show you how to create files with the drive api, and the api is easy to use. worst case you can make direct ajax calls and oauth flow.

Comment: Is your application for your own use?  A group of co-workers?  The general public?  Do the users all have Google accounts or not?  gspread hasn't already change the code over?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in that `gspread` is using older technology. [GData APIs](http://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory) are the previous generation of Google APIs. While not all GData APIs have been deprecated, [all **newer** Google APIs](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis) do **not** use [the Google Data protocol](http://developers.google.com/gdata).  One alternative is to get the `gspread` maintainers to upgrade their library (steps & learning resources below), esp. if you're already comfortable and/or have applications that depend on it heavily.

The current way to use today's Google APIs is to get [the Google APIs Client Library for Python](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python) (it's as easy as `pip install -U google-api-python-client` [or `pip3` for Python 3]). Once you have that, you'll be using the [Google Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive) in lieu of the Documents List API and the [Google Sheets API](http://developers.google.com/sheets) instead of the older Google Spreadsheets API.

FYI, the Sheets API is much more powerful & flexible than older API releases. Here's one [code sample](http://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python) from the official docs to help get you kickstarted. However, here are more "real-world" examples of using the API you can learn from (videos plus blog posts):

- [Migrating SQL data to a Sheet](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/introducing-google-sheets-api-v4.html) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/06/using-new-google-sheets-api.html))
- [Formatting text using the Sheets API](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/formatting-cells-with-the-google-sheets-api.html) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/09/formatting-cells-in-google-sheets-with.html))
- [Generating slides from spreadsheet data](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/generating-slides-from-spreadsheet-data.html) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/11/generating-slides-from-spreadsheet-data.html))

The latest Sheets API provides features not available in older releases, namely giving developers programmatic access to a Sheet as if you were using the user interface (create frozen rows, perform cell formatting, resizing rows/columns, adding pivot tables, creating charts, etc.). As you can see, the Sheets API is primarily for **document**-oriented functionality as described above, while **file**-oriented access such as copy, import/export, etc., is done with the Drive API instead. Here are a few examples of using it:

- [Listing your files in Google Drive](http://youtu.be/Z5G0luBohCg?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=4) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2014/11/authorized-google-api-access-from-python.html))
- [Google Drive: Uploading & Downloading Files](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/01/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) plus "Poor man's plain text to PDF converter" (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html)) (*)
- Exporting a Google Sheet as CSV blog [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/07/exporting-google-sheet--as-csv.html) only

(*) - TL;DR: upload plain text file to Drive, import/convert to Google Docs format, then export that Doc as PDF. Post above uses Drive API v2; [this follow-up post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/migrating-to-new-google-drive-api-v3.html) describes migrating it to Drive API v3, and here's a [developer video](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/01/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) combining both "poor man's converter" posts as yes, the new v3 came out just after I finished the previous content. `:P`